# Reload scapy conf

Tags: python, module, scapy, system-calls

I'm using scapy twice in different modules throughout my app. One of the modules however creates a new multiprocessing.Process and within this does a syscall (308) into a network namespace. At this point I need to reload scapy so it redefines its conf to align with the new processes environment.

For example a diff is below of the normal import ($1), and the net namespace import ($2)

```
0a1
> 0
2c3
< AS_resolver = <scapy.as_resolvers.AS_resolver_multi instance at 0x1af3c68>
---
> AS_resolver = <scapy.as_resolvers.AS_resolver_multi instance at 0x7f6cd218bc68>
22c23
< iface      = 'TR_BR'
---
> iface      = 'lo'
34c35
< neighbor   = Ether -> ARP Ether -> IPv6 Dot3 -> IP Ether -> Dot1Q Ether -> L...
---
> neighbor   = Ether -> LLC Ether -> ARP Ether -> IPv6 Ether -> Dot1Q Ether ->...
47c48
< route6     = Destination Next Hop iface src candidates fe80::/64 :: UNTR_BR ...
---
> route6     = Destination Next Hop iface src candidates ::1/128 :: lo ::1
```

Comment: So I can change the iface with conf.iface = 'lo' and I found conf.route.resync() which recalculates the routes...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved with a change to:

```
conf.iface = 'lo'
conf.route.resync()
```

Comment: It might be better for future readers if you explain a bit more about why this works.